# How can I make a widget shortcode to control all the widgets?

Tags: functions, shortcode, widgets

First things first,

I am making a theme in which I have make some widgets that are listed below.

1. About Me Widget
2. Subscribe Me widget
3. AD widget

Now what I thought that if I could implement my widget using shortcodes.

So to implement widgets using shortcodes I have made a function that implements the widgets using the classname and it works fine but as not expected.

**So what's the problem?**

The Problem, widgets that I have made in my theme are different with each other Obesily.

**What I mean?**

I mean that My all three widgets contains the title, to display.

1. If I add the about us widget using shortcode it gives me the error undefined index title ( with the directory location of my about us file ). NOTE: The solution of this problem is mentioned below.
2. If I add the Subscribe me widget using shortcode no undefined title error. The reason is the index is same but.
3. In AD widget I got three errors and they are undefined index ad_title, ad_img_url, ad_link_url. I know why the errors are coming -> Reason: index name are different.
4. Two More things.

   1. I am having one more problem with about me widgets and that is the the is only displaying but the about me content is not why? If I try two add the about me index then also nothing got printed.

      ```
          extract(shortcode_atts(array(
              'widget_name' => FALSE,
              'title' => '',                  
              'aboutMe' => ''     // BY  ADDING  THE  INDEX  TITLE
          ), $atts));
      ```
   2. The error occurs for index only in the input fields. It does not occurs in the textarea field that I have used for about me content.

   **How I solved the First problem?**

   I have solved the first problem by adding the index name.

   ```
   function widgetShortcodes( $atts ) {

       global $wp_widget_factory;

       extract(shortcode_atts(array(
           'widget_name' => FALSE,
           'title' => '',                  // BY  ADDING  THE  INDEX  TITLE
       ), $atts));
       // do shortcode actions here

       $widget_name = esc_html($widget_name);

       if (!is_a($wp_widget_factory->widgets[$widget_name], 'WP_Widget')):
           $wp_class = 'WP_Widget_'.ucwords(strtolower($class));

           if (!is_a($wp_widget_factory->widgets[$wp_class], 'WP_Widget')):
               return '<p>'.sprintf(__("%s: Widget class not found. Make sure this widget exists and the class name is correct"),'<strong>'.$wp_class.'</strong>').'</p>';
           else:
               $class = $wp_class;
           endif;
       endif;

       $args = array(
           'before_widget' => '',
           'after_widget' => '',
           'before_title' => '',
           'after_title' => ''
       );

       ob_start();
       the_widget($widget_name, $atts, $args);
       $output = ob_get_contents();
       ob_end_clean();
       return $output;

   }
   add_shortcode( 'widget','widgetShortcodes' );
   ```

**What I want to know?**

I want to know that I have to add each and ever index name if I make a new widget with different or new index. Is there would be the easy or more dynamic way to do this.

I think I have one and that is to make the shortcode for each and every widget but that's a long process.

*Any Suggessions would be appriciated?*

By the way I want to notify you that I have make this widget shortcode function using this link -> [Call a Widget with a Shortcode](https://digwp.com/2010/04/call-widget-with-shortcode/)

**UPDATE:**

The Function is only working for two wordpress inbuilt widgets and they are.

1. Archives
2. Recent_Posts

and the function is not giving error but also not previewing any result

1. RSS
2. Tag_Cloud
3. Nav_Menu_Widget

other wp classes triggering the errors.

1. Calendar
2. Categories
3. Links
   4.Meta
   5.Pages
   6.Recent Comments
   7.Search (a search from)
   8.Text